# How to detect response time user? JavaScript + Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a beginner Rails developer. 
The problem is: On the derivation of the word in a foreign language and a form for entering the user response (textfield and submit):

```
<%= form_tag check_translation_path, method: :put do %>
  <%= label_tag        :translation, "Translation:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag   :translation %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :card_id, @card.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Check"  %>
<% end %>
```

I want measure the response time of the user(time from the moment the page is loaded and before submit the form) and send the value to the controller checks the user's response(review_controller.rb) to calculate the next time the show this word. And in the same controller sends the result of the user input.
How can I do this?
Sorry for my English